# Webpack execute file in the global scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to include the library https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp in my webpack project without success so far.

If I try via npm the project cannot be created giving a huge error stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/onzag/7f36cf7a6e6ab4b80dfad0f1a6113b68

When I try executing the browser file jimp.js with webpack using the script loader (these execute the files's content in the global context) I get:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: encode is not defined`

If I try to use the raw loader which will just get me the content of the script, and then create a script, and set the content to the whole content of the script so that it gets executed I get.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'window' of object '#'`

Also if I assign an id to the parent script it'll be exposed in the main window. `<script id="name"></script>` will create a variable `name` in the global context that contains that node.

Everything behaves fine if I put it in the HTML as an external src, however that's not optimal.

Comment: Do you want to run `jimp` library on client/browser side?

Comment: So how do you expect to have on client side `fs` module? This module is reserved for node backend apps.

Comment: Can you share your `webpack` config?

Comment: @gnerkus https://gist.github.com/onzag/59b6d5850fb5cd2c84b0a785560eea09